# Run phonegap application on Android device

Tags: android, html, cordova, terminal, phonegap-build

Sorry if this question is vague.

When I try to get my Phonegapp application onto an Android device to test, it does not work.

It works fine on iOS.

I have searched the web and everything suggested is not working for my problem.

I am running the command:

`adb devices`

This returns:

```
List of devices attached 
BX90374LPY  device
```

I am then running:

```
phonegap run android --device=BX90374LPY
```

This results in:

```
Unknown platforms: BX90374LPY
```

If I run:

```
phonegap run android --device
```

I get:

```
[phonegap] executing 'cordova run android --device'
[phonegap] completed 'cordova run android --device'
```

But nothing happens on my device.

What am I doing wrong, or missing?

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT / UPDATE**

It seemed I was having a problem with my $PATH variable for ANDROID_HOME

Here's what fixed it for me:

Open you bash profile:

`open -e .bash_profile`

Then add this to the file when it opens:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.1.2
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH
```

Save this file, and restart terminal. Job Done.

Comment: Try using only `phonegap run android` if you only have one device listed on `adb devices`. If it doesn't work either, search for an APK file in your project folder, and install it on your device with `adb install -r yourapp.apk`

Comment: You have USB debugging set up on your phone?

Comment: @SubjectiveEffect Yes I have done.

Comment: And have you also allowd installation of applications from unknown sources?

Comment: @QuickFix I have. i think it may be a $PATH problem

Comment: cordova build android works? (if you have issue with the path it should be when building, not when running)

Answer (score 7):

Try using `phonegap run android --verbose` and it should give you more details on the problem.

Comment: I am getting this: BUILD FAILED
/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.1.2/tools/ant/build.xml:601: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.1.2/tools/ant/build.xml:653: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.1.2/tools/ant/build.xml:698: null returned: 1

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of looking around here's what fixed my issue:

It seemed I was having a problem with my `$PATH` variable for `ANDROID_HOME`

Here's what fixed it for me:

Open you bash profile:

```
open -e .bash_profile
```

Then add this to the file when it opens:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.1.2
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the error using:

`$ phonegap run android --verbose --stacktrace`

```
* What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 7 cannot be smaller than version 10 declared in library D:\MilleniumTech\platforms\android\build\intermediates \exploded-aar\android\CordovaLib\unspecified\debug\AndroidManifest.xml
        Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="org.apache.cordova" to force usage
```

Comment: Hi, Jonathon. Do you know how to fix it? Thanks

Comment: When I run `phonegap run android --verbose --stacktrace` I don't get the error you provided. Instead, I get `ERROR running one or more of the platforms: CordovaError: The provided path "/Users/*/Google Drive/Websites/angular-phonegap/platforms/android" is not an Android project.
You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project`

Comment: Did you try to delete platform folder?

Comment: Why would I do that? If you mean `platform remove` then re add it with `platform add` yes I did that. Didn't help, sadly. Any other ideas?

Comment: Please, just try to delete this folder and try again. It will be create again when you do `phonegap run android`

Comment: Like I said, in response to your last question, I have already tried that. That's not the fix to my issue. Thanks for the attempt anyway.

Comment: The solution is to edit the config.xml file in the root of your project. Change the 7 in the following line to 10.

    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="7" />

Answer (score 1):

PhoneGap 5.0.0-0.28.1 on Windows 7 here.

I tried running `adb install -r myapp.apk` and the app was successfully installed so I investigated further and figured out that a line had to be fixed in the Node script `platforms\android\cordova\lib\device.js`. This line:

```
var cmd = 'adb -s ' + resolvedTarget.target + ' install -r -d "' + apk_path + '"';
```

should be changed to:

```
var cmd = 'adb -s ' + resolvedTarget.target + ' install -rd "' + apk_path + '"';
```

or optionally (since the `-d` option doesn't work on some platforms):

```
var cmd = 'adb -s ' + resolvedTarget.target + ' install -r "' + apk_path + '"';
```

You can check the value of the `cmd` variable yourself if you add a line such as `console.log(cmd);` below the above mentioned line and then run `phonegap run android --verbose` (with the `--verbose` option) in order to see the output. I will know `cmd` needs fixing if you execute it at the command prompt (e.g. `adb -s ...`) and it doesn't output a `Success` message.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have valid **SSL connection** with your phone ?

If you **don't have** valid this connection , your computer don't have **the drivers required**. Please check driver.